# Best aesthetically solution to overflowing data in a table

Tags: website-design, usability, tables, html, wrapping

I have the following table which I created as follows:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<style type="text/css">  
html {  
    background-color: #fff;  
}  
body{  
    text-align:center;  
}  
table{  

    border-collapse:collapse;  
}   
table,th, td{       
    border: 4px, solid;     
}    

th{  
    text-transform:uppercase;  
}  


div {  
    width: 720px;  

    border: 1px solid #000;  

    margin: 0 auto;  
    margin-left:150px;  
    padding:0;  
}  

</style>   
</head>  
<body id="article">  
<div >  
<table>  
<tr>  
    <th>First Name</th>  
    <th>Last Name</th>  
    <th>Date</th>  
    <th>Notes</th>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
    <td>Jill</td>  
    <td>Smith</td>   
    <td>20-12-2013</td>   
    <td>aaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Jill</td>  
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Eve </td>  
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>John </td>  
    <td>Doe</td>   
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Adam </td>  
    <td>Johnson</td>  
    <td>20-12-2013</td>  
    <td>AAAa</td>  
</tr>  


</table>  
</div>   


</body>  
</html>
```

The problem is that the 3rd column wraps arround `-` due to the big value in the last column of the first row.
I can solve this with `table-layout:fixed` and either `overflow:hidden` or `word-wrap: break-word`.

I don't really like the first approach since the data will be hidden, i.e. the user will not be able to read them.

I don't really like the second approach since the first row will be much vertically larger than the others.
 What is the best aesthetically solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Wrap the data with an elipsis at the end**. What this does is, it uses **known vocabulary** to show there is more than what is visible.

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

becomes

```
AAAAAA...
```

then you can **use a tooltip to show the entire content**, use hyperlink or the column can be expanded, depending on your design.

Comment: Or even better are ellipses buttons ``...``

Comment: @AthomSfere:How do I create ellipses buttons?

Comment: @Jim: The true ellipsis is a [separate punctuation character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) like this: …

Comment: When you have to ellipses you can display the detail entire cell content) in a tooltip which displays in roll over.

Answer (score 5):

There is a third approach, **text-overflow**:

```
.shorten {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* or "clip" */
}
```

See [dev.w3.org](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow) for more information.